# Deeply Nested If...Then

Tags: java

This code (mangled) is being flagged by PMD for being too deeply nested.  I personally have always written code this way in any language I've coded in - especially large database-driven for-loops.

Is this coding style really frowned-upon?  I find it to be the most maintainable and cleanest.

```
    for (MyList MyRegistry : listJSP) {
        if (meta.containsKey(MyRegistry.getFieldName()) && MyRegistry.getOrderType().equals(orderType)) {

            String CustomerInput = meta.get(MyRegistry.getFieldName())[0];
            String jspFieldName = MyRegistry.getFieldName();

            if (MyRegistry.getErrorsCheck()) {
                mapErrors = valUtil.adTextContainsErrors(CustomerInput, cms.getRegex("VALIDATION"));
                if (mapErrors.containsKey(Boolean.TRUE)) {
                    mapValidationErrors.put(jspFieldName, mapErrors.get(Boolean.parseBoolean("true")));
                    log.info("Errors " + "{}: ", CustomerInput);
                }
            }

            List<JSPFieldValidation> jSPFieldValidation = cms.getJSPFieldValidations(orderType, MyRegistry.getFieldName());
            for (JSPFieldValidation jspf : jSPFieldValidation) {

                String valRule = jspf.getValidationRule();

                if (valRule.equals("REQUIRED")) {
                    if (isEmpty(CustomerInput)) {
                        mapValidationErrors.put(orderType, orderType);
                        log.info(CustomerInput + "{}: ", valRule);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Pattern p = cms.getRegex(valRule);
                    if (p != null) {
                        if (!isValid(CustomerInput, p)) {
                            mapValidationErrors.put(orderType, orderType);
                            log.info(CustomerInput + "{}", valRule);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Might be better suited on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: There are infinite books and articles online describing why this is not a good way to write code. I am curious... Why do you think it is "the most maintainable and cleanest"?

Answer (score 4):

Static analysis tools give subjective advice based upon generally accepted (or configurable) standards.

So no one is going to be able to give you the correct answer as to if your loops are too deeply nested.

If you don't like the recommendations PMD gives you I suggest configuring PMD differently so it doesn't run that rule or runs it with different parameters.

With that said, it would be trivial to extract some of that logic into smaller methods.

Answer (score 2):

When you have nested loops and many ifs and else the [Cyclomatic Complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) of the method increases. It basically indicates the difficulty for testing.

Split your method to smaller methods or you can just ignore it if you seem ok with the code.

Comment: I think it is worth clarifying... refactoring out methods will not reduce the CC of your code as a whole, it just decreases the complexity of each method on it's own. And you are very right, this makes testing your code MUCH easier!